# SOQL query to load Task returns nothing, but I see task in UI

Tags: soql, api, rest-api, activities

I am trying to load all tasks of a contact via SOQL query:

```
SELECT Id, Subject FROM Task WHERE WhoId = 'contactId'
```

This query returns only partial list of Tasks. I.e. in UI I see tasks directly attached to this Contact which are not being returned as part of the result for this query.

I googled a bit and found out that I might need to query an ActivityHistory sobject and yes querying it returns me "missing" tasks as well:

```
SELECT (SELECT Id, Subject FROM ActivityHistories) FROM Contact WHERE Id ='contactId'
```

So, my question is that an expected behavior? I.e. there is no way to load all the Tasks using 1 query and I have to load both Tasks and AcitivityHistories?

Also, interestingly, I couldn't reproduce this situation in a developer account: I've registered a Task with subject 'other' that took place in the past and in UI it is displayed in Activity History section, but I receive it is a part of normal Task loading query. So, i am not really sure why the Task in originally described situation is not returned with simple Task query (i.e. only in ActivityHistories query)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Salesforce archives older activities. From the docs:

> **[How can I view activities that are more than a year old?](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/faq_activities_how_can_i_view_activities.htm)**
> Salesforce archives older activities according to the conditions below. These
> activities can be viewed only in the **Printable View** of the associated
> record, the Activity History related list of the associated record,
> export files, or by clicking **View All** on the Activity History related
> list. You can search for archived activities using advanced search.
> Administrators can also delete archived activities using Mass Delete.
>
> 1. Events with a due date greater than 365 days old
> 2. Closed tasks with a due date greater than 365 days old
> 3. Closed tasks without a due date that were created more than 365 days ago

When these conditions are meet* the Task no longer appears in SOQL queries against the [Task](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) sObject. Instead you need to use the [ActivityHistory](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm) "view" in a relationship query from the parent sObject.

* It appears the archival process isn't immediate. If you set a Tasks Due Date to be more than one year old it will still appear against the Task sObject for a period of time. Most likely Salesforce has a scheduled job to process the archival.

---

Useful notes from the docs:

- [ActivityHistory](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm) a "read-only object contains information about each activity related to  an object". "This object helps you replicate the related list functionality of the user interface."
  So ActivityHistory is more like a view that collectively returns both Tasks and Events **and archived records**.
- [Task](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) "Represents a business activity such as making a phone call or other
  “to-do” items. In the user interface, task and Event records are
  collectively referred to as activities."
- [Event](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) "Represents a calendar appointment event. In the user interface, Event
  and Task records are collectively referred to as activities."

---

A couple of other thoughts as to why you might see a record in ActivityHistory but not in Task.

1. The record in question is an Event and not a Task. Check the keyprefix in the Id. If it is 00U then you are dealing with an Event. A Task would be 00T. Or check the IsTask ActivityHistory column.
   *As per the discussion, we have confirmed that you are dealing with a task*
2. There might be sharing rules/permission issues hiding the record in question. Does the user running the query have the View All Data permission?
3. The task might have a due date greater than 365 days old and has been archived by Salesforce. See [How can I view activities that are more than a year old?](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_activities_how_can_i_view_activities.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: thanks for the response, though I don't understand what you're trying to say. I know that one cannot query the ActivityHistory directly (take a look at my example query - it works, and it doesn't query directly). And like you mentioned tasks + events are activities, hence tasks end up in Activity History section of the UI when they are done (or took place in past). My question is why might Task only be seen via ActivityHistory sobject? (and how to replicate that)

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting there in a very round about way. I suspect that the record in question actually an Event rather than a Task that you are seeing via the ActivityHistory. Check the keyprefix on the problem record. Is it 00U or 00T?

Comment: It is `00T` and it has `IsTask=true`. So, it is actually a Task, right?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely a Task. So what happens if you query that Task directly? `SELECT Id, Subject, WhoId FROM Task WHERE Id = '00TYourIdHere'`. Does the WhoId have the expected value?

Comment: I cannot load that task directly by id: i get empty result. I guess that's the issue here - if i could load it by id, it would also be present in list of all Tasks. When I look at ActivityHistory object representing that task - I see the correct WhoId (id of the contact that task expected to be associated with)

Comment: It might be that the Task in question has been archived. How old is the due date on the problem record? Is it older than a year?

Comment: Yes! One is dated June 2010, the other has system fields set to 2007, but doesn't have a due date (though it is also completed). So, i understand that when activities archived they are only available via ActivityHistory?

Comment: @antonlitvinenko Yes, that certainly seems to be the case. As ActivityHistory is setup to replicate the UI behaviour you can see archived tasks for a single lead/contact.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to replicate that in developer account? i just created a task with due date in the past (2007) and see it both as result in Tasks and ActivityHistories queries.

Comment: That would make another good question. It would appear that the archival isn't immediate. Salesforce may be performing some form of scheduled process. Maybe give it some time to come round and process the record.

Comment: ok! Daniel, could you update your initial answer to include info about archiving? I'd like to accept it, but i think notion of archiving is correct answer here, not the initial info you've provided. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is coming way too late to help you, but I also ran into this issue and, while the accepted answer is correct information, it doesn't offer a solution.

If you are querying using apex, simply adding ALL ROWS to your query will return tasks that have been moved to ActivityHistory

So instead of

SELECT Id, Subject FROM Task WHERE WhoId = 'contactid'

Just do

SELECT Id, Subject FROM Task WHERE WhoId = 'contactid' ALL ROWS

This does not work in the developer console query editor, but I have confirmed that it does work in Apex